# How to interface HCSR04 ultrasonic sensor with ATxmega256A3?

Tags: pulse, atxmega

I have to interface HCSR04 with [ATXMega256](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATXMEGA256A3). I am using the `TCC0` Timer in Capture mode with setting it to capture pulse width, using Event System Channel 0 source: Port A Pin0.

Anyway, my code is shown below in one file using `USARTE1` to send the measurement to another terminal:

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/io.h>

#define USART_Format_Set(_usart, _charSize, _parityMode, _twoStopBits) \
(_usart)->CTRLC = (uint8_t) _charSize | _parityMode | \
(_twoStopBits ? USART_SBMODE_bm : 0)

#define USART_RxdInterruptLevel_Set(_usart, _rxdIntLevel) \
((_usart)->CTRLA = ((_usart)->CTRLA & ~USART_RXCINTLVL_gm) | _rxdIntLevel)

#define USART_Baudrate_Set(_usart, _bselValue, _bScaleFactor) \
(_usart)->BAUDCTRLA = (uint8_t)_bselValue; \
(_usart)->BAUDCTRLB = (_bScaleFactor << USART_BSCALE0_bp) | (_bselValue >> 8)

#define USART_Rx_Enable(_usart) ((_usart)->CTRLB |= USART_RXEN_bm)
#define USART_Tx_Enable(_usart) ((_usart)->CTRLB |= USART_TXEN_bm)

#define USART_IsTXDataRegisterEmpty(_usart) (((_usart)->STATUS & USART_DREIF_bm) != 0)
#define USART_PutChar(_usart, _data) ((_usart)->DATA = _data)

void usart_putchar (uint8_t data)
{
    while (!USART_IsTXDataRegisterEmpty(&USARTE1));
    USART_PutChar(&USARTE1, data);
}

volatile uint16_t pulseWidth = 0;

int main(void)
{
    cli();
    int16_t count_a = 0;

    // System clock External oscillator 16 MHz
    OSC.XOSCCTRL = OSC_FRQRANGE_12TO16_gc | OSC_XOSCSEL_XTAL_16KCLK_gc;
    OSC.CTRL |= OSC_XOSCEN_bm;
    CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
    while ((OSC.STATUS & OSC_XOSCRDY_bm) == 0);
    OSC.CTRL &= ~(OSC_RC2MEN_bm | OSC_RC32MEN_bm | OSC_RC32KEN_bm | OSC_PLLEN_bm);
    PORTCFG.CLKEVOUT = (PORTCFG.CLKEVOUT & (~PORTCFG_CLKOUT_gm)) | PORTCFG_CLKOUT_OFF_gc;

    // Port initialize 
    PORTB.DIR =0x01; // Trig Port at PB0
    PORTA.DIR = 0x00; // Echo Port at PA0
    PORTA.PIN0CTRL = PORT_ISC_BOTHEDGES_gc;
    PORTE.DIR = 0x80; // USART at USARTE1

    // Timer TCCO in capture pulse width mode
    EVSYS.CH0MUX = EVSYS_CHMUX_PORTA_PIN0_gc;
    TCC0.CTRLB = TC0_CCAEN_bm | TC_WGMODE_NORMAL_gc;
    TCC0.CTRLA = TC_CLKSEL_DIV1_gc;
    TCC0.CTRLD = TC_EVACT_PW_gc | TC_EVSEL_CH0_gc;
    TCC0.INTCTRLB = TC_CCAINTLVL_LO_gc;
    TCC0.INTFLAGS = TCC0.INTFLAGS;

    // USARTE1 
    USART_Format_Set(&USARTE1, USART_CHSIZE_8BIT_gc, USART_PMODE_DISABLED_gc, false);
    USART_RxdInterruptLevel_Set(&USARTE1, USART_RXCINTLVL_LO_gc);
    USART_Baudrate_Set(&USARTE1, 0xCE5 , -5); // 9600
    USART_Rx_Enable(&USARTE1);
    USART_Tx_Enable(&USARTE1);

    // PMIL
    PMIC.INTPRI = 0x00;
    PMIC.CTRL |= PMIC_LOLVLEX_bm;
    sei();

    while (1) 
    {
        PORTB.OUT = 0x01; // trig the sensor 
        _delay_us((20));
        PORTB.OUT = 0x00;
        count_a = pulseWidth / 58;

        // pulseWidth = 0;
        uint8_t hByte = count_a >> 8;
        uint8_t lByte = count_a & 0xff ;
        count_a = 0;
        usart_putchar(hByte);
        usart_putchar(lByte);
        _delay_ms(250);
    }
}

ISR(TCC0_CCA_vect)
{
    pulseWidth = TCC0.CCA;
}
```

In Atmel Studio 7 I have written a `.stim` file to generate pulses with 10 ms, and in simulation I was able to capture this pulse which is equal to \$10000/58 = 172 cm\$, but with the real xmega, the terminal received random bytes. Also I checked the `USARTE1` sending process and it works fine.

Have you any suggestion please to determine where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that you don't wait for the echo to return.

Reading from https://randomnerdtutorials.com/complete-guide-for-ultrasonic-sensor-hc-sr04/ :

> "The HC-SR04 barely works to 10 feet giving a total path length of 20
>   feet and a path time of about 20ms so set the timeout to something
>   above that, say 25 or 30ms."

So the measurement could take up to 20 ms to arrive. I think you should reset pulseWidth to 0 before starting a sample, then wait until you got a value:

```
pulseWidth = 0;
PORTB.OUT = 0x01; // trig the sensor 
_delay_us((20));
PORTB.OUT = 0x00;
while (pulseWidth == 0) ;  //Waiting here.
count_a = pulseWidth / 58;
```

Or better yet, delay until a timeout, to catch if the echo goes missing.

By the way, the link I quoted only pings for 10 us, not 20 us.

Still, your code should catch the pulseWidth value registered on the previous loop, so something else could be wrong here. You might need to reset the input capture timer, as is done in https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/xmega-input-capture

If those ideas don't help, if you can check the pins with an oscilloscope, that would help you narrow down if the signal arrives as it should.

Comment: it is right, as you mention i have to wait for echo, also there is a mistake in calculations, i missed to to multiply by 1/Timer_FREQ to map the timer ticks to corresponding real time